# yaml variable in python

Tags: python, pycharm, yaml

I'm trying to use values from a YAML file to assign to functions or variables in a python module.
What I've tried: created a python module to decode the YAML file and imported it to the main python module e.g.:

config.yaml:

```
1. arguments: 
2.    variable_one: value_one
3.    variable_two: value_two
etc...
```

parsed_yaml_file.py:

```
1. import yaml
2. a_yaml_file = open("config.yaml")
3. parsed_yaml_file = yaml.load(a_yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

main.py:

```
1. from parsed_yaml_file import *
2.
3. def set(x):
4.    value_one
5. etc...
```

For me line 1 in main.py remains gray. I was expecting it to change when I included the value in the function for example.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't yet used the `yaml` module, but I'm guessing that you imported your `arguments` into `parsed_yaml_file` variable, and not into `variable_one` or `variable_two` like you might've liked.

Furthermore, following the [yaml docs](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), they will be imported as a dictionary into python to the variable you called `parsed_yaml_file`, like:

```py
parsed_yaml_file = { 
    arguments: { 
        variable_one: value_one,
        variable_two: value_two,
        # ...
    }
}
```

Thus if you want to access `value_one`, you should use:

```py
parsed_yaml_file['arguments']['variable_one'] # out: value_one
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, I hope it at least helps you understand a bit more about how python files interact with each other.

Anyways, good luck! And have fun learning!

Comment: I think there should be: `parsed_yaml_file['arguments']['variable_one'] # out: value_one`

Comment: And you are totally right! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Just like @Felipe Whitaker said, you are actually creating the object

```
parsed_yaml_file = {
'arguments': {
  'variable_one': 'value_one',
  'variable_two': 'value_two'
  }
}
```

inside `parsed_yaml_file.py` file. To access the variables you must do as Felipe mentioned.

If you are hell bent on having the variables available to you in a separate module than `main.py`

Then you can do something like this in `parsed_yaml_file.py`

```
import yaml

a_yaml_file = open("config.yaml")
parsed_yaml_file = yaml.load(a_yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

globals().update(parsed_yaml_file.get("arguments"))
```

This will set the attributes `variable_one = value_one` likewise for `variable_two =  value_two` in the namespace of `parsed_yaml_file.py`.

Disclaimer: Personally, I think it's much cleaner to have an intentional data structure for holding the variables, so you can choose!